# How does the purification until analytical grade work?

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, petrochemistry

What are some industrial methods used for puryfing organic solutions, like toluen, until it is analytical grade? Im not looking for details just some names and somewhere to keep reading

Comment: Multiple distillations